# Filter DOM element by id starting with a letter using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to find out a solution to get all elements of page using selenium to populate test values later. I am able to get all elements, but I would like to filter out the elements those are starting with letter 's'. So I can get elements  like sFirst, sLast, sAddress etc. I can use teh code below. But I am not sure what should be after 's' here.

```
// I am not sure what should be after 's' here.
List<WebElement> allEle = driver.findElements(By.id("s *"));
```

OR

```
// instead of all elements, need to find ids starting with 's'
List<WebElement> allEle = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));


//iterate and print
for (WebElement ele : allEle ) {
  ele.getAttribute("id");     // id of each element
  ele.getText();

  System.out.println ("Element :" + ele.getAttribute("id") + ": Test :" +ele.getText());

}
```

Edit note: Added for loop ending brace inside code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find elements not starting with s as follows:

```
List<WebElement> allEle = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*:not([id^='s'])"));
```

If you're trying to find all elements starting with s:

```
List<WebElement> allEle = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='s']"));
```

Edit:

To filter out elements that start with sA, sB, etc, I think this would work:

```
List<WebElement> allEle = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='s']"));
String letters[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
foreach (String letter in letters)
{
    allEle = allEle.findElements(By.cssSelector("*:not([id^='s" + letter + "']));
}
```

You can also try this, but I think it might be slow:

```
List<WebElement> allEle = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='s']" + 
    ":not([id^='sA']," + 
    "[id^='sB']," + 
    "[id^='sC']," + 
    "[id^='sD']," + 
    "[id^='sE']," + 
    "[id^='sF']," + 
    "[id^='sG']," + 
    "[id^='sH']," + 
    "[id^='sI']," + 
    "[id^='sJ']," + 
    "[id^='sK']," + 
    "[id^='sL']," + 
    "[id^='sM']," + 
    "[id^='sN']," + 
    "[id^='sO']," + 
    "[id^='sP']," + 
    "[id^='sQ']," + 
    "[id^='sR']," + 
    "[id^='sS']," + 
    "[id^='sT']," + 
    "[id^='sU']," + 
    "[id^='sV']," + 
    "[id^='sW']," + 
    "[id^='sX']," + 
    "[id^='sY']," + 
    "[id^='sZ']")));
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I am trying to filter out the elements that starts with s+[all starting with Upper Case]. I tried this ("[id^='s[A-Z]']")), didn't work.Any suggestion?